# How can I get a column "bonded" with an INDEX function into a formula in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I currently have this table on Excel:

[image]

I have applied this formula to the last column, so that it matches the first and the second column:

=IF(ISNA(MATCH(A6;$B$1:$B$6;0));"";INDEX($A$1:$B$6;MATCH(A6;$B$1:$B$6;0);2))

How can I get the third column into the upper formula so that it appears next to the matching names? (The idea is that the second and the third column are bonded)

Like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minor change:

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH(A6;$B$1:$B$6;0));"";INDEX($A$1:$C$6;MATCH(A6;$B$1:$B$6;0);{2,3}))
```

Example at different address:

`=IF(ISNA(MATCH(A21,$B$21:$B$26,0)),"",INDEX($A$21:$C$26,MATCH(A21,$B$21:$B$26,0),{2,3}))`

[image]

*In current versions of Excel, the 2nd column will `SPILL`.  In older versions, you may need to select both columns and enter it as an array formula with `ctrl+shift+enter`*

Comment: Thanks Ron! It is not working at the moment on my Excel. I am trying to get it done on google sheets but I can only get the names, no the Info. Do you know if this can be done in google sheets? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @MAA What version of Excel? Windows or MAC?

Comment: It is on Excel 2016 on Windows. @RonRosenfeld

Comment: @MAA Did you enter it as a [legacy array formula](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-an-array-formula-e43e12e0-afc6-4a12-bc7f-48361075954d) as I mentioned in my answer?  I do not believe 2016 supports dynamic arrays.

Comment: Yes, and I get this result @Ron Rosenfeld: Manish Manish
Nitin Nitin
Manoj Manoj
Ankit Ankit
Sushil Sushil I am using this formula: =IF(ISNA(MATCH(A22;$B$21:$B$26;0));"";INDEX($A$21:$C$26;MATCH(A22;$B$21:$B$26;0);{2,3})) and using what you said of selecting both cells, then introducing the formula and then selecting control+shift+enter.

Comment: @MAA Your array list separator is likely incorrect for your regional settings.  You need to replace the comma in: `{2,3}` with the correct separator for your locale.  Possibly a `\\`?

Comment: @MAA To determine the proper separator for your locale, enter a formula representing a horizontal array in some cell (eg `=A1:D1`.  Then select that cell; put your cursor in the formula bar, and hit `F9`.  The formula bar will then show something like `{0\0\0\0}` showing you horizontal array separator you should be using.

Comment: It was the '\' that needed to replace the comma. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of INDEX/MATCH this can be accomplished with FILTER/COUNTIF:
`=FILTER(B1:C6,COUNTIF(A1:A6,B1:B6))`
It filters the given range `B1:C6` where `COUNTIF(A1:A6,B1:B6)` equals 1.
[image]

PS  If you would want the list of non-matching values you can use the same but you could add `=0`: `=FILTER(B1:C6,COUNTIF(A1:A6,B1:B6)=0)`

Office365 is required for this solution.